# OSM data confusing line and polygon

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, spatialite

Taking some OSM (*.osm) data downloaded from Geofabrik I have created a Spatialite database using spatialite_osm_map. Now I have problems, because some of the data that is supposed to be in the form of polygons appears in the database as polylines, which I can't style properly. As an example, objects tagged "natural=wood" appear correctly as polygons in the DB while objects tagged "landuse=forest" appear as lines.

I think this must be something to do with what I've seen called the "multipolygon problem". At present I am loading the affected objects into QGIS, exporting them as shapefiles and then polygonising these.

Is there a better way of working?

I know little about Spatialite and OSM data.

Here is a screenshot illustrating the problem. The "polygon" selected by the info tool is in fact a polyline.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Openstreetmap, polygons can be build either by one closed way, or by a number of ways, which form a closed way. Those ways have to be part of a "relation" of type "multipolygon".

I dont know your tool, but the safest way to have those polygons correctly is to use a Postgis database filled with osm2pgsql.

A sample osm-id from your data could help investigating further.